# $location.path(...) adds an ID to url

Tags: angularjs

If the user has become logged out, I want to send the user to the login page, but it fails. I have this configuration:

```
webShopApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', { 
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', 
        controller: 'LoginController' 
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/:id?/?products', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/products.html', 
        controller: 'MenuController' 
    });
});
```

Note the "/:id?/?" inte the code for products. Let's say the url is 'index.html#/45/products'. If the controller discovers that the user is logged out, it calls

```
$location.path('/login');
```

If I console.log the $location.path(), it says '/login' as expected, but the url in the browser is 'index.html#/45/login'. Why is the '45' (the id) still there, and how do I get rid of it, ie, redirect to 'index.html#/login' without the id from the previous path?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `window.location = 'yourUrl';` instead of `$location.path('/login')`; in this case. But in this case, the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

see if you need to workout in pure angularjs, so please avoid javascript terms and jquery terms i.e. windows.location and $location.path; Better option is always to route the user to login page whenever the user gets logout from the App.
for this you can specify it at the routing level i.e.

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/login"});
```

or you can say a logout link on clicking of which user will be redirected to login page

```
$routeProvider.when('/logout', { 
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', 
        controller: 'LoginController' 
    });
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: According to this document, $location.path is the right way to go: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location.

Comment: see that doc only telling about the difference between windows.location and $location.path or it's telling more which one is compatible with angularjs, so have you tried out what i suggested?

Comment: Right after that, it says: "When should I use $location? Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser." That is exactly what I want to do. When in an ajax call, the backend responds with 401, in our case, it means that the user has become logged out (session has timed out). Then I need to redirect to the login form. I don't understand how I could do that with $routeProvider.when(...)